# node.js is listening on port, but cant connect from the outside on Ubuntu Server

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I have a Node.js server listening on port 9000

Internally I can run "curl localhost:9000"

And it can retrieve the GET request.

But when I try and connect to the IP from the outside on port 9000, it doesnt work.

Do I need to open the port publicly?

Its an Amazon EC2 instance.

What do I need to do?

SOLVED:
had to add tcp inbound into security groups. Thank you very much
VALUES:
Custom TCP Rule
TCP
0 - 9000
0.0.0.0/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like a firewall issue. There are two things to look for, first is IPTABLES, which will show you the firewall rules on the local server. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/IptablesHowTo

With AWS instances, they also belong to Security Groups, and you will have to edit this security group to allow traffic on port 9000 as well. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html